# How to redirect a page with a previous dialog in JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, dialog

I have a dialog(A), that redirect to a xhtml of people registration, that is call by another xhtml (B), when the xhtml of people registration is called by the B, I can return normally, but when the origin is the dialog(A) the xhtml return to B, I'm using primefaces. a peace of code of people.xhtlm are as follow:

```
<f:facet name="footer">
<p:commandButton onstart="#{navegationBean.unlockPage()}" oncomplete="#{navegationBean.unlockPagina()}" id="backButton"
    icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w" value="#{label.back}" actionListener="#{pessoaBean.pageRedirect}" update="@form"
    immediate="true" />

<p:commandButton onstart="#{navegationBean.unlockPage()}" oncomplete="#{navegationBean.unlockPage()}" id="salvarButton"
    icon="ui-icon ui-icon-check" value="#{label.save}" update="#{navegationBean.idFormContent}" rendered="#{peopleBean.bottonSaveActive}"
    actionListener="#{peopleBean.save}" />
```

I'm trying to use a method inside the PeopleBean, It is as follow:

```
public void pageRedirect(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

if ( this.origin == 1 ) {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext extContext = ctx.getExternalContext();
    String url = extContext.encodeActionURL(ctx.getApplication().getViewHandler()
            .getActionURL(ctx, "/pages/gathering/roles/people_roles_dialog.xhtml"));

    try {
        extContext.redirect(url);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new FacesException(ioe);
    }
}
}
```

I also have the follow classes...
PeopleNavegationHandler:

```
package br.com.webrecad.bean.people;

import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.webrecad.aplicacao.abstractbean.AbstractNavegacaoHandler;
import br.com.webrecad.model.people.People;

@Named
public class PeopleNavegationHandler extends AbstractNavegationHandler<PeopleBean,   People> {

public PeopleNavegationHandler() {
    super(PeopleBean.class, People.class);
}

public void listByFilters() {
    super.bean.reloadInstances();
    super.setList();
}
}
```

AbstractNavegationHandler:

```
package br.com.webrecad.aplication.abstractbean;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import br.com.webrecad.aplication.navegation.PageStage;
import br.com.webrecad.aplication.navegation.NavegationBean;
import br.com.webrecad.aplication.servicelocator.BeanServiceLocator;

public class AbstractNavegationHandler<T extends AbstractBean<E>, E> {

private NavegationBean navegation;

protected AbstractBean<T> bean;

private String classeName;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractNavegationHandler( Class<T> bean, Class<E> class1 ) {
    BeanServiceLocator locator = BeanServiceLocator.getInstance();

    navegation = (NavegationBean) locator.getManagedBean(NavegationBean.class);
    this.bean = (AbstractBean<T>) locator.getManagedBean(bean);

    classeName = StringUtils.lowerCase(class1.getSimpleName());
}

public void setListar() {
    bean.setPageStage(PageStage.LIST);
    navegation.setCurrentPage("/pages/" + classeName + "/list_" + classeName + ".xhtml");
}

public void setRegister() {
    bean.setPageStage(PageStage.REGISTER);
    navegation.setCurrentPage("/pages/" + classeName + "/" + classeName + ".xhtml");
}

public void setEdit() {
    bean.setPageStage(PageStage.EDIT);
    navegation.setCurrentPage("/pages/" + classeName + "/" + classeName + ".xhtml");
}

public void setPreview() {
    bean.setPageStage(PageStage.PREVIEW);
    navegation.setCurrentPage("/pages/" + classeName + "/" + classeName + ".xhtml");
}
}
```